# If $h$ divides $|G|$, not necessary that $G$ has a subgroup of order $h$

Tags: group-theory, math-software, gap

> if $h$ divides $\# G$, then it is not necessarily that $G$ has a subgroup of size $h$

which can be related to Lagrange Theorem
$[G:H]=\frac{\#G}{\# H}$ in the case when the subgroup exists, however it is not generally true such as in the case of $\mathbb A_4$ with order of 12 and having no subgroup of 6. So

**How can you demonstrate the proposition of the highlight in GAP?**

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Somehow you have included the first example to your highlighted statement in the PS, but in a totally irrelevant way. Look, $A_4$ has order $12$, but it does **not** have a subgroup of order $6$.

Comment: @DavidHill PS tried to make question sound more introductory to GAP, removed the PS, introductory command in the history :)

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding what you are after. Do you want to search for groups where the converse to Lagrange's theorem holds? Or are you looking for where it fails.

Comment: @DavidHill as in the highlight, I understand this as the converse: we only know that a group $G$ exists and $h\mid\#G$, we don't know whether the a subgroup exists of order $h$ in the group $G$ so the goal is to find demonstration that $h\mid\#G\not\rightarrow H\leq G$ where $H$ is of the order $h$. The existence of $H$ is not known.

Comment: It's still just unclear what an answer to your question should look like, to me at least. Do you want someone to load the alternating group of degree $4$ into GAP, check the orders of all its subgroups, and print "6 divides 12 but there is no subgroup of order 6"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check whether a particular group would be a counterexample to the (wrong) converse of Lagrange's theorem you probably cannot do better than to calculate the subgroups. In GAP, the command

```
ord:=Set(List(ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(G),x->Size(Representative(x))));
Difference(DivisorsInt(Size(G)),ord);
```

will return a list with the orders of subgroups of $G$ and in the second command determine the orders for which there are no subgroups.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G =A_{4}$. Then 6 divides the order of G but G does not have a subgroup of order 6.

Proof:  Note that a 2-cycle is always an odd permutation and any m-cycle can be written as a product of (m-1) 2-cycles and so an m-cycle is odd if and only if m is even, this tells us the shapes of cycles contained in $A_{4}: id, (ab)(cd), (abc)$. The number of p-cycles in $S_{n}$ is given by $(p-1)!\binom{n}{p}$ and in particular there are 8 cycles of length 3 in $A_{4}$.

Now suppose G has a subgroup H of order 6. Then since $[G: H] = \frac{12}{6} = 2$, H is normal in G. Since G has 8 elements of order 3 not all of them are contained in H so we pick $\sigma$ which is not in H. $K = \langle \sigma \rangle$ is a subgroup of G.

Since H is normal, HK is a subgroup of G and we have the important formula: $|HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|}$ giving us that HK is a subgroup of G of order 18 but this contradicts the LaGrange's Theorem and so such an H cannot exist.

Comment: This does not answer the question (though it is a valid counterexample). It seems the OP is looking for some kind of GAP routine.

Comment: The OP seemed unable to state clearly what it is that he is looking for. I do not find it interesting to look for an algorithm that will produce a lot of counter examples to the converse of a theorem when there are already a considerable few one can produce with a pencil.

Comment: I don't disagree with you about whether the question is interesting.